# Can i still able to use obsolete asset?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

So i just downloaded [Google Sign-In For Unity](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity) , and my unity 2018.3.0f2 say there are 4 obsolete file in the asset and asking whether to delete them or keep them ( obsolete mean if i keep them they are just a waste of space ). So before i continue , is it still possible to use the asset ? or is there any way to make it possible to use obsolete asset ?

I have searched in the internet and unity seemed to have api updater but it is for script and it doesn't seem able to update asset because i didn't find any info about updating assets .

Comment: Usually, a script is obsolete because a method or a reference has been made so. The console offers a solution in most cases. It could be that you just need to update the scripts.

Comment: but it is asset not script and i can't update it . my question is which one from this 3 fact is the right one : 
(1) I still can use the asset if i didn't delete the asset file that unity offer me to delete

Comment: (2) i still able to use the asset even if i delete the file , (3) i can't use them at all and just delete them and switch to another asset

Comment: if i continue without checking i may end up with problem in the future ,and if i switch to another asset without checking i might missing a good opportunity because it is currently the best asset for what i am looking for . so please help me , thank you .

Comment: What specifically does it say is obsolete?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781018/the-meaning-of-obsolete ... as long as stuff isn't marked as `deprecated` you can go on use it in the meantime the [`[Obsolete]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute) attribute has an optional parameter that if set to `true` makes your compilation fail .. otherwise it is a warning but will still work.

Comment: @derHugo thank you :) my bad that i didn't understand the meaning of obsolete deeply , but now i understand it ,so it means i still can use obsolete assets BUT not deprecated assets . Meanwhile , you can put that comment in answer section if you want reputation.